# Outputting Docx4J to PDF File

Tags: docx4j

I am using the commercial version of docx4j and we have a requirement to output the document to PDF format. I understand there are two options. One is to use an online converter tool. The other is to use a legacy docx4j-export-fo.  We can't use the first approach due to the company firewall rules, so the system needs to be self contained, which means option 2.

My pom looks like the following:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.plutext</groupId>
            <artifactId>Plutext-Enterprise</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-Internal</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

The exclusions were to address the issues detected by the maven enforcer. When attempting to covert the word document to PDF, the test fails with the following:

Looks like your endpoint URL 'http://localhost:9016/v1/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/convert' is wrong

This seems to indicate the first approach is being used rather than the second, which is not the desired result.

I've also tried using apache poi to do the conversion, but that fails with NPEs. Can anyone suggest how to get round this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The current options are set out at https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2020/09/office-pptxxlsxdocx-to-pdf-to-in-docx4j-8-2-3/

Whether export-fo is used depends on:

```
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.FOExporterVisitor");
```

Can you confirm docx4j-export-fo is on your classpath?  Perhaps you have security settings prohibiting reflection?

You can try invoking it directly:

```
        FOSettings settings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
        settings.setOpcPackage(wmlPackage);
        settings.setApacheFopMime("application/pdf");
        Docx4J.toFO(settings, outputStream, Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The library was indeed in my classpath, but I was missing xmlgraphics-commons-2.4.jar, which I installed manually.  I am still unable to generate anything though due to a NPE: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.TraitSetter.setVisibility(TraitSetter.java:615)
 at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.BlockLayoutManager.addAreas(BlockLayoutManager.java:334)

Comment: That's odd, possibly because you are excluding fontbox?

Comment: the fontbox library is definitely in my classpath, I can see a lot of debug output when running the code you told me to try. It just fails when it somewhere around the Xml Sereializer: 22:04:22.575 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.utils.XmlSerializerUtil - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.TraitSetter.setVisibility(TraitSetter.java:615)

Comment: Does this happen with every docx, even a simple "Hello World"?

Comment: with a docx with nothing more than "hello world" , the exception is: DEBUG org.docx4j.convert.out.common.wrappers.ConversionSectionWrapperFactory - No body level sectPr in document